# $scope.$watch not detecting changes in directive in same module

Tags: angularjs

I'm implementing a watch in the controller, when user toggles a button. I have a watch inside the directive and that is working, e.g. it detects that the scope variable has changes but if I have a watch inside the controller it does not detects

```html
    <button toggle-button active-text="Yes" inactive-text="No" ng-model="light.state">Show millions</button><br>
```

here is the code:

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('fiveYearOverview', ['fiveYearOverviewServices', 'fiveYearOverviewDirectives'])
    .controller('fiveYearCtrl', [
        '$scope', 'reports',
        function ($scope, reports) {

            //not working
            $scope.$watch('lightState', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue)
                    console.log("I see a data change!");
            }, true);

        }
    ])
    .directive('toggleButton', function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                activeText: '@activeText',
                inactiveText: '@inactiveText',
                lightState: '=ngModel'
            },
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,

            template: '<div>' +
                '<span ng-transclude></span> ' +
                '<button class="btn" ng-class="{\'btn-primary\': state.value}" ng-click="state.toggle()">{{activeText}}</button>' +
                '<button class="btn" ng-class="{\'btn-primary\': !state.value}" ng-click="state.toggle()">{{inactiveText}}</button>' +
                '</div>',

            link: function postLink(scope) {

                scope.lightState = scope.inactiveText;
                scope.state = {
                    value: false,
                    toggle: function () {
                        this.value = !this.value;
                        scope.lightState = this.value ? scope.activeText : scope.inactiveText;
                        console.log(scope.lightState);

                        //working
                        scope.$watch('lightState', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                            if (newValue)
                                console.log("I see a data change!");
                        }, true);

                    }
                };
            }

        }
    });
```

What is that i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

By defining a scope in the directive you are creating an *isolated* scope for it. Thats why you cant access its members from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

`lightState` is being declared in a scope below that of `fiveYearCtrl` making it inaccessible as outlined [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/LDNz_TQQiNE/ygYrSvdI0A0J).

An alternative solution could be to define the callback function in `fiveYearCtrl` and call it from the directive.

```
.controller('fiveYearCtrl', [
    '$scope', 'reports',
    function ($scope, reports) {
        this.consoleLog = function (newValue, oldValue) {
            if (angular.isDefined(newValue))
                console.log("I see a data change!");
        };
    }
])

link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) 
{
    scope.lightState = scope.inactiveText;
    scope.state = {
        value: false,
        toggle: function () {
            this.value = !this.value;
            scope.lightState = this.value ? scope.activeText : scope.inactiveText;
            console.log(scope.lightState);

            //working
            scope.$watch('lightState', ctrl.consoleLog, true);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for quick response. The console.log er just a way for me to know if the event has been fired. The goal is to update some data in the controller when user hits the button, so I'm just trying to hit a function in the controller from the directive, which would update a datasource?

Comment: I know, this was just an example to show you how it could be done. You can create whatever function you like in the controller and just call it from the directive.